# Axios returns ECONNREFUSED very often while CURL works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios

I've read many topics here, but nothing same was helpful. My problem is that I often get `ECONNREFUSED` error while using `axios.all` .. `get` on *nodejs* (in 50% of get requests). In the same time, curl works great.
This in my js code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function makeGetRequest () {
   let config = {
      headers: {"User-Agent": 'curl/7.64.1'}
    };
   try {
      const [BYN, RUR] = await axios.all([
         axios.get('https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/145', config),
         axios.get('https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/298', config),
       ]);
          return [BYN.data, RUR.data];
         
   } catch(error) {
      return error
   }
  }

makeGetRequest().then((value) => {
   console.log("VAL: ", value)
})
```

As you can see, I tried to manipulate headers in order to imitate curl's but this doesn't work.
The command:
`curl https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/145`
works fine. But I need SSR response for my gatsby site.

Comment: Is it possible the API restricts simultaneous requests from the same IP? What happens if you await the two get requests sequentially instead of using axios.all?

Comment: @selfagency I thought about it. But can't findout it exactly. I tried to make curl requests by sh script 2 times for second and nothing was blocked. While on nodejs it works sometimes ant then stops for some reason. If I use one axios request - nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

The error:
ECONNREFUSED
is the underlying HTTP protocol connection error which means the the HTTP server didn't accept your connection.

Probably it's not a problem with your code at all, you just need to ensure rates and agents allowed by the web server your trying to reach to call that API.

As [selfagency](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857453/selfagency) commented, you may be reaching the max rate of requests per seconds, and IMO it's likely to be your case because you are dispatching 2 **concurrents** requests.

So, try the following:

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function makeGetRequest() {

  let config = {
    headers: { "User-Agent": "curl/7.64.1" }
    };
    
  try {

    const BYN = await axios.get(
      "https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/145",
      config
        );
        
        const RUR = await axios.get("https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/298", config);
        
        return [BYN.data, RUR.data];
        
  } catch (error) {

        return error;
        
    }
    
}

makeGetRequest().then(value => {
  console.log("VAL: ", value);
});
```

This way you will be doing only 1 request at a time, so maybe you bypass the rate limit. BTW this is very common for free mode APIs that want you to pay to leverage your usage.

Comment: It didn’t help. I see that it’s something with nbrb.by host. But can’t find out. I tried to run curl in verbose mode but don’t see any “special” headers or methods there. Is it possible that axios or nodejs mashing my response with some hidden attributes that can cause such a hosts behavior?

Comment: It's weird because you are able to make successful requests using nodejs + axios, so you facing an intermittent error which makes me think is something about DDOS protection in the host or it's really throttling your requests. Why don't you make a script (could be even in NodeJs) to try to dispatch multiple cURL concurrent requests, then you will know if it's something related to NodeJs and/or Axios.